# Why does a device show up twice on my dhcp table?

Tags: router, dhcp

I bought a new router yesterday, but I dont think that's relevant because on my previous router it happened too. The only change is that my first router wasn't dualband and this new one is. So that makes me think that might be the cause, but I also dont understand why it would list the device twice when I'm not using both wifi connections simultaneously.

What happens is two of my devices show up on the dhcp table twice. 
Its always the same two. My galaxy S5(GS5) phone and my Galaxy tablet(GT). Something leads me to believe that there's something about galaxy devices that causes this to happen. But what?

Or it could be the routers because on my old router I had dd wrt and on my new router I have dd wrt.

But idk why. What makes them show up twice?

[image: table]

Im guessing it has something to do with the interface. But I dont understand any of that. eth1 is ethernet. br0 is bridge. Idk what a bridge is but a quick google search says it connects a network to another network. How does a tablet become a bridge then when all it is is connected to my router which connects to my isp modem. Wouldnt that mean all of them were bridges since they all connect to my router and then my modem? So I dont understand that.

Answer (score 1):

A bridge merges ("flattens") two or more physical or logical networks. This can be a mixing of technologies -- ethernet, FDDI, token-ring, ARCNET, etc. which are all very different networking technologies. Or it can be spanning what would otherwise be independent (i.e. "routed") interfaces (eg. vlans, wired ethernet, and wifi.)

What you are seeing is the "layer-3" (IP) interface (*br0*) and the physical "layer-2" interfaces making up that bridge (*vlan2* -- the "LAN" ports, *eth1* and *eth2* -- the wifi radios)

Answer (score 0):

The dualband allows different channels for different protocols (802.11 with 2.4GHz b/g/n and 5GHz a/n) connecting older devices. All wireless device traffic will go through one WAP interface br0.

A bridge is just old term for switch which is OSI layer 2 (like MACs) and the Ethernet interfaces are OSI layer 3 (like IP Address) for routing. So the statistics/traffic are being organized by eth0 and eth1 (layer 3) kind of like dividing up the WAP br0 interface.